# Can not move extents after pvmove --abort

Tags: lvm

I wanted to move extents from one disk to another, both have the same size:

```
# pvmove /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc1
```

Unfortunately, pvmove hung at 99.99% for several hours and I decided to issue a `pvmove --abort`.
The moving was stopped and the LV is still functional, however it is not possible to re-run the `pvmove` anymore:

```
# pvmove /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc1
  Insufficient free space: 727303 extents needed, but only 0 available
  Unable to allocate mirror extents for kujira/pvmove0.
  Failed to convert pvmove LV to mirrored.
```

But, the target device has exactly 727303 free extents.
I can even create new LVs on the PV, but `pvmove` does not like to move the extents.
The issue is, that the LV I tried to move was resized once, and is split into two segments:

```
# lvs --all -o lv_name,devices
  LV             Devices
  srv            srv_rimage_0(0),srv_rimage_1(0),srv_rimage_2(0)
  [srv_rimage_0] /dev/sda1(0)
  [srv_rimage_0] /dev/sda1(703489)
  [srv_rimage_1] /dev/sdc1(0)
  [srv_rimage_1] /dev/sdd1(703489)
  [srv_rimage_2] /dev/sdb1(0)
  [srv_rimage_2] /dev/sdb1(703489)
  [srv_rmeta_0]  /dev/sda1(703488)
  [srv_rmeta_1]  /dev/sdd1(703488)
  [srv_rmeta_2]  /dev/sdb1(703488)
```

`srv_rimage_1` resides now on `sdc1` and `sdd1`:

```
# pvdisplay --maps /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc1
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd1
  VG Name               kujira
  PV Size               <5,46 TiB / not usable <1,57 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              1430791
  Free PE               703488
  Allocated PE          727303
  PV UUID               boRXi6-6fjo-Ga8Y-iVzJ-qdb4-g3Q7-TASCwx

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 703487:
    FREE
  Physical extent 703488 to 703488:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rmeta_1
    Logical extents     0 to 0
  Physical extent 703489 to 1430790:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rimage_1
    Logical extents     703488 to 1430789

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               kujira
  PV Size               <5,46 TiB / not usable <1,57 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              1430791
  Free PE               727303
  Allocated PE          703488
  PV UUID               ZikJzc-Au3G-O327-Rsw5-2AoY-Wwu3-NzBfBf

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 703487:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rimage_1
    Logical extents     0 to 703487
  Physical extent 703488 to 1430790:
    FREE
```

Can I somehow still move everything from `sdd1` to `sdc1`?

```
  LVM version:     2.03.02(2) (2018-12-18)
  Library version: 1.02.155 (2018-12-18)
  Driver version:  4.35.0
  Configuration:   ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --exec-prefix= --bindir=/bin --libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --sbindir=/sbin --with-usrlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-optimisation=-O2 --with-cache=internal --with-device-uid=0 --with-device-gid=6 --with-device-mode=0660 --with-default-pid-dir=/run --with-default-run-dir=/run/lvm --with-default-locking-dir=/run/lock/lvm --with-thin=internal --with-thin-check=/usr/sbin/thin_check --with-thin-dump=/usr/sbin/thin_dump --with-thin-repair=/usr/sbin/thin_repair --enable-applib --enable-blkid_wiping --enable-cmdlib --enable-dmeventd --enable-dbus-service --enable-lvmlockd-dlm --enable-lvmlockd-sanlock --enable-lvmpolld --enable-notify-dbus --enable-pkgconfig --enable-readline --enable-udev_rules --enable-udev_sync
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is the allocation policy of LVM. I found this blogpost which explains the issue: https://tim.mattison.org/db01b8858c1748a7aed1649d57aefaa3

Looking at the manpage of pvmove:

```
 --alloc contiguous|cling|cling_by_tags|normal|anywhere|inherit
              Determines the allocation policy when a command needs to allocate Physical Extents (PEs) from the VG. Each VG and LV has an allocation policy which can be changed with vgchange/lvchange, or overriden on the command line.  normal applies common sense rules
              such as not placing parallel stripes on the same PV.  inherit applies the VG policy to an LV.  contiguous requires new PEs be placed adjacent to existing PEs.  cling places new PEs on the same PV as existing PEs in the same stripe of the LV.  If there are
              sufficient PEs for an allocation, but normal does not use them, anywhere will use them even if it reduces performance, e.g. by placing two stripes on the same PV.  Optional positional PV args on the command line can also be used to limit which PVs the command
              will use for allocation.  See lvm(8) for more information about allocation.
```

My best guess is that the issue arises from the split up LV on the PVs, here on one of the non-moved disks:

```
--- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 703487:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rimage_2
    Logical extents     0 to 703487
  Physical extent 703488 to 703488:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rmeta_2
    Logical extents     0 to 0
  Physical extent 703489 to 1430790:
    Logical volume      /dev/kujira/srv_rimage_2
    Logical extents     703488 to 1430789
```

The second extents come from the lvresize process. It looks like that pvmove will correctly move all three if asked for the first time, but refuses to move them when one of the `rimage` is already on the other PV.

As written in the blogpost, `pvmove --alloc anywhere [...]` works.

According to `man 8 lvm`, one should see the allocation debug code when using `-vvvv`.